# Ansible playbook with environment variable

Tags: ansible

I trying to setup a gitlab pipeline to create a rabbitmq standalone machine, and i use rockandska/ansible-role-rabbitmq to do this. But in defaults/main.yaml e need to create some users with password, but i dont want to commit passwords in my git repo. So i need to get pass values from gitlab ci/cd environments variables.

But i'm not getting this, i trying to create a file in

vars/main.yml

```
---

rabbitmq_admin_pass: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}
```

and in defaults/main.yml i use

```
rabbitmq_users_to_create:
  - user: admin
    password: "{{ rabbitmq_admin_pass }}"
    vhost: /
    configure_priv: .*
    read_priv: .*
    write_priv: .*
    tags: administrator
```

but doesn't work, it creates the user but with "${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}" pass :D

ps.
I already put in .gitlab-ci.yml variables directive, like that:

```
variables:
  ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASSWORD: ${ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASSWORD}
  RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}
```

someone have some idea to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the environment variables as "extra_vars" when running `ansible-playbook`.

```
ansible-playbook ... --extra-vars "rabbitmq_admin_pass=${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}"
```

This prints out the secrets on command line, though.

Another possibility is using the [lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html).

```
password: "{{ lookup('env','RABBITMQ_PASSWORD') }}
```